# Power Automate Excel sheet name

Tags: excel, power-automate

I have a Power Automate that retrieves a specific Excel file attachment from my Outlook email and saves it to a shared drive. Afterwards, I need to upload the contents via sql to a table but sql doesn't like the name of the worksheet. I am changing the name of the file when I save it to the shared drive but I don't see how to change the name of the worksheet.

I use:

When a new email arrives
Apply to each
     Attachments
     Create file

How can I change the name of the file?

Answer (score 0):

When you save the file with Power Autoamte your can submit the new name directly within the CreateFile method like here https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/create-file-in-sharepoint/td-p/343844

Comment: In my opinion this is close to but not really a link-only answer, so I am neither downvoting nor flagging it as not-an-answer. But you might give a few more details of how to do it right here, i.e. go a little on with the summary of what you linked to.

Comment: Can you send a screenshot from your current flow? I guess you save the file on the shared drive with the flow as well?